# Saber si un formulario se ha validado

Tags: jquery, submit

Tengo una duda que me esta volviendo loco por que no se si tiene solución, estoy metiendo un codigo jquery dentro de $(document).ready para que en todos los formularios de mi pagina al enviarlos se de deshabilite el boton submit de tal manera que el usuario solo pueda pulsarlo una unica vez evitando que pueda crear registros duplicados. Bien, el codigo que os muestro  mas abajo funciona perfectamente ya que al enviar un formulario se deshabilita el boton submit de dicho formulario pero claro y ahi esta el problema, se deshabilita **siempre** se envie finalmente el formulario o no, ya que estos formularios tienen unas validaciones (), yo lo que necesito es que se deshabilite el boton submit **solo si el submit tiene exito** por lo tanto onsubmit no me vale ya que si finalmente ese formulario no se envía por que no cumple las validaciones el boton deveria seguir habilitado para que el usuario pueda corregir el formulario y poder volverlo a enviar. ¿De que manera puedo saber si el formulario al que hago referencia se envía o si por el contrario se interrumpe el submit al validarlo?
Mil gracias!!!

```html
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").on("submit","form",function(event){
      $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", true);
  });


});
```

Comment: ¿De que manera validas esos campos?¿ Restricciones **HTML**? ¿A través de una función validadora desde el cliente (Ejemplo: Javascript)? ¿Desde el servidor (Ejemplo: PHP)?

Comment: Valido los campos con una funcion JS que devuelve true (ejecuta el submit) o false (no ejecuta el submit) la cosa es ¿como puedo saber si el evento submit se ha ejecutado finalmente o no? ya que con onSubmit yo solo puedo saber si se ha evocado al evento submit pero no saber si se ha ejecutado con exito.

Comment: Te preguntaba el método de validación porque ahí está el kit de la cuestión. Si el validador te devuelve  `true` significa que se va a enviar el formulario. Podrías o bien deshabilitar e `submit` en esa misma función antes de lanzar el `return true` o bien tras capturar la respuesta de la función validadora desde donde la llamas y comprobar que esta es `true.`

Comment: Deshabilitar el submit en la funcion validadora es lo primero que se me ocurrió el problema es que el proyecto es enoooooorme e ir función por función me llevaria muchisimo tiempo por eso queria saber si pudiera capturar el evento event y saber si de verdad se ejecuta para poder hacer una función generica como la que he puesto en mi pregunta. Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿El formulario lo envías por AJAX?

Comment: No uso Ajax, se envia por post sin usar Ajax.

Comment: La función `submit()` no tiene *callback* así que si no lo haces vía AJAX no te quedan muchas más opciones, hasta donde sé, que las que ya te he mencionado. Si hubiese sido por AJAX podrías haber aprovechado el *success* que te proporciona el método,.

Comment: @phpMyGuel La validación es en el lado cliente, entiendo.

Comment: Deberías poner el código que usas para hacer que se valide el formulario, con lo que tienes en la pregunta no sé qué tipo de validación usas y por tanto no sé cómo modificarla

Comment: @PabloLozano Sí, es lo que yo entendí también, pero si los datos se hubieran enviado por AJAX significaría que el `success` de esa llamada confirmaría que todo a ido **OK** (habiendo pasado la validación) y hubiese sido un buen momento para deshabiltar el botón de `submit`.